# How to get records when angular pagination click

Tags: angularjs, codeigniter

I'm using dir-paginate for displaying records and pagination.
for that I have created one function

```
$http.get("admission/getinfo").success(function(result){
    $scope.admissiondata = result;
});
```

and pass this data to dir-paginate.  Now what's happens here suppose I have more than thousand records , all these records are get once, that's why it takes more time to fetch and display data.
Now My question is . when user click the pagination that time next whatever records fetch. suppose I have set 10 for pagination then next 10 records is display in codeIgniter and angularjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use limit,offset in your backend, like

```
$http.get("admission/getinfo?pageno=1").success(function(result){
   $scope.admissiondata = result;
});
```

and when page no change, use callback function `on-page-change`.
Check this:
https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/tree/master/src/directives/pagination#dir-pagination-controls